# Why doesn’t the focussing anode diverge the electron beam again?

Tags: electrons, electric-fields, electronics

Consider this diagram of a focusing anode in a CRT:
[image]

**Question:** Why does the electron beam not diverge again when it enters the focussing anode (or accelerating anode) while leaving the pre-accelerating anode (or focussing anode)?

I think the answer is that it *does* diverge but *less* than it converges at both entrances. And since it converges *first*, the resultant is relatively convergent. The following is how I show it:
[image]

Is it correct?